# LCD Display connection

Tags: microcontroller, spi, lcd, display

How to connect this http://docdroid.net/ngqg LCD Display to microcontroller? It is ILI9341 based.

Is it possible to connect only SPI/LED pins and leave every other input pin floating or I need to connect every pin(HSYNC, VSYNC etc.) and control them myself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That display requires you to send each frame as a frame in its entirety.  You need to send the full pixel data for each and every pixel with all the right timing.  Kind of like driving a VGA monitor.

While it is possible to do it with a generic microcontroller, that microcontroller must:

- Have enough RAM to store the entire frame buffer
- Be fast enough to generate the clocks and data streams while still leaving you enough processing time to do what you want to do.

There are specialized microcontrollers that have extra hardware in them to specifically drive this kind of display.  The one I have used in the past is the [PIC24FJ256DA210](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/devices.aspx?dDocName=en547869).

Comment: Thank you Majenko, can I use this HW for example http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT800.html ?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Another popular one is the SSD1963.

Comment: To conclude, I have 2 options: 
1) to use HW controller which controls frames between MCU and LCD
2) to write driver myself, i.e. connect LCD to MCU roughly like https://learn.adafruit.com/system/assets/assets/000/013/453/medium800/adafruit_products_tftshieldv2.png?1388769644 and use SPI to RD/WR ILI9341 register

Thank you! :)

Comment: Did I get it right? I am a bit confused about serial interface with this display. Should I leave them open because FT800 drives sync and RGB pins each frame cycle? Thank you for your honest help! :)

Comment: The serial interface is for configuring the display and setting different parameters.  The parallel RGB interface is for sending the raw video information.  You need them both.

Comment: So for example, I connect FT800 with SPI1 to MCU and drive the video content(images, lines etc.), and connect the display with SPI2 to MCU and set its parameters. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yep, that should do nicely.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but how it is allowed to tie DB[17..0] pins together(i.e. adafruit https://learn.adafruit.com/system/assets/assets/000/013/453/original/adafruit_products_tftshieldv2.png?1388769644)?

Comment: Is that even the same display?  The original data sheet you pointed to is lacking about 90% of the information you need to actually use it.  Maybe it can be switched into an SPI-only mode. Maybe it can't. Maybe it comes with different chips / configurations for different purposes.  Who knows? I would suggest picking a different display with a well-known chip embedded in it.

Comment: I don't know, it has the same IC driver(ILI9341) so I assumed that the approaches would be the same. I asked the manufacturer about the details :D

Comment: Right, now we know the display chip it uses things are very different.  The datasheet you have there appears to be just for the LCD glass, not the driver.  ILI9341 is made by someone else and placed on the glass during manufacture.  It performs the same functions as the FT800 chip, etc.  You can just drive it direct with SPI and nothing else. It has its own framebuffer built in.

Comment: "You can just drive it direct with SPI and nothing else" . That's what I initially taught, but I was confused with HSYNC/VSYNC and other 30+ pins :)

Comment: The ILI9341 can be configured in multiple ways including 18-bit parallel. It's much much faster with the parallel interface (obviously) but will work with just SPI.  Personally I usually use displays with parallel and drive them with a PIC32's PMP for ultra high speed updates (like on the Picadillo-35T).

Comment: Since I won't use it for video and need to draw primitives(ASCII mostly), I think SPI approach would suit me well.